# why jps does not show nodemanager

Tags: java, cluster-computing, nodes, ubuntu-14.04, hadoop2

I have setup a hadoop 2.4.1 cluster on 3 virtual box ubuntu 14.04 LTS machines. when I try jps on slave nodes then it shows only datanode daemon running, while from browser on port 8088, it shows both slaves are up, so that mean nodemanagers are running, also when I submit a job then it also complete it is confirm that nodemanagers are running on both slave machine, so why jps shows only datanode not nodemanager

Comment: Did you test each node separately? Testing if Single-node cluster setup works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to restard the hadoop by calling "$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh".